# I am trying to create a telegram bot, I am getting error in command handler it is for casual talk

Tags: python, bots, telegram

Below is my telegram bot code.
I am trying to get input from user and return eventually I will give input to my ML model:

```
 def chat(s):
      return s

  def handle_message(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
              print("inside")
              tx = update.message.text
              re = chat(tx)
              update.message.reply_text(re)
  def main():
        updater = Updater("API_KEY",use_context=True)
        dp = updater.dispatcher
  
        dp.add_handler(CommandHandler(Filters.text,handle_message))
        dp.add_error_handler(error)
        updater.start_polling()
        updater.idle()
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
File "C:\Users\NAMIT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-        packages\telegram\ext\commandhandler.py", line 161, in __init__
self.command = [x.lower() for x in command]
 TypeError: '_Text' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
In order to get help, you will need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `MessageHandler` instead of `CommandHandler`

```
#dp.add_handler(CommandHandler(Filters.text, handle_message))
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, handle_message))
```

---

Minimal working code:

```
import os
import logging
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, CommandHandler, Filters

TOKEN = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_TOKEN')

def error(update, context):
    logger.warning('Update "%s" caused error "%s"', update, context.error)

def chat(s):
    return s

def handle_message(update, context):
    print("inside")
    tx = update.message.text
    re = chat(tx)
    update.message.reply_text(re)
              
def main():
    updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    #dp.add_handler(CommandHandler(Filters.text, handle_message))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, handle_message))
    dp.add_error_handler(error)
    
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

main()
```